# Swift referencing UIImage gathered from Users photos into a Dict

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a page in storyboard where a user can change their nickname and user Icon.
The Users, username is predefined and Im using this along with NSUserDefaults to store minimal information on said user;

```
 UserData['UserID'] = ["Nickname":"Johnny English", "UsersProfile": "abc123"]
```

I load a page where the user can modify their Nickname and Profile picture, using **UIImagePickerController** I can find an image in the users library, and then replace the stock image on the page with the new profile one.

But I can't see to find a way to either reference the image within the iOS directories or move the image to inside the app and reference it that way.

So far I have:

```
  func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        UserIconImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        UserIconImageView.image = pickedImage
        // Add the UsersProfile to the UsersProfile entry for this User
        //detailsOfUser["CustomImage"] = pickedImage
        // Change the 'Done' button to a 'Save'
        self.completeButton.title = "Save"
    }
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Whats the best way to proceed here? 
Is it better to reference the image or move it to within the app? if so how?

```
 detailsOfUser["CustomImage"] = does a url / referencing string go here?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I've worked with similar problem. All of anwsers I've found were saying that it is no way to get the reference of this image choosen by UIImagePickerController and my solution was this:

First of all, I've found the local Documents folder path for choosen picture:

```
 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let docsFileHandler: FileManager = FileManager.init()
    let documentDirectoryPath: String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first!
```

Then, I've taken a selected picture and it's name with extension:

```
        let imageFromPicker = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]!
        var imageID = (info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL).absoluteString as NSString
        let imageExt = (info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL).lastPathComponent! as NSString
```

Next step, I've found the picture name from assets library. I've used the part with ID and extension, but you can save it for example as a user name. I've added the new name for the picture to the Document folder path.

```
        let startRangeName = imageID.rangeOfString("id=")
        let endRangeName = imageID.rangeOfString("&")

        let idRange = NSMakeRange(startRangeName.location + startRangeName.length, endRangeName.location - startRangeName.location - endRangeName.length - startRangeName.length)

        imageID = imageID.substringWithRange(idRange)

        var writePathForFile = (documentDirectoryPath as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageID as String)
        writePathForFile.appendContentsOf(imageExt as String)
```

The last step was to save the selected picture to the Documents folder with created name:

```
        let imageDataFromPicker = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageFromPicker as! UIImage)

        imageDataFromPicker?.writeToFile(writePathForFile, atomically: true)
```

In this point, you can use **writePathForFile** for your  **detailsOfUser["CustomImage"]**

Comment: Worked like a charm! One thing to mention. FileManager line needs to be: `let docsFileHandler: NSFileManager = NSFileManager.init()`